# Why does 4s iphone change to vibrate when I put phone in my pocket?

Tags: iphone

Maybe I'm nuts but it seems my iphone 4s switches from normal (audible) mode to vibrate when I put my phone in my pocket.  Anyone else having this weird issue?

Answer (score 1):

On the left-hand side of your iPhone is this little switch (ring/silent). The plausible answer to your question is, that you turn the switch on/off by accidentally touching it when you put your phone in your pocket. This happens to me all the time as well.

When the switch is turned from *on* to *off* your phone will vibrate one time.

Answer (score 0):

It's also plausible that the proximity sensor is switched on and there is a setting tied to it.

Answer (score -1):

Well there is a option in settings>Accessibilty>Vibration turn it off to avoid this .Hope this helps

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.